# JAWS Screen Reader not working on java application

Tags: java, jaws-screen-reader

Trying to get JAWS to work with a java application but it doesn't seem to want to read anything. The Access Bridge appears to be working because i don't have the same issue with NVDA(it works fine).

I can't even get JAWS to read the menu items of Netbeans. Seems to be ok on all other non-java applications.

Any tips on what i can look at? Any reasons why NVDA would work and JAWS won't?

EDIT: Should mention that i'm using JAWS in 40 minute demo mode. Could that make a difference?

Thanks

Comment: I assume you are using a relatively recent version of JAWS and Java?  Did you enable the access bridge according to these instructions: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/access/enable_and_test.html  It is possible that access bridge is not enabled but NVDA can still read some basic "here is a frame" type stuff while JAWS doesn't even bother.  Are you getting detailed navigation info with NVDA to be confident the access bridge is indeed working?

Comment: @Pace Using JAWS 17 and Java 8. NVDA is reading everything, menus name, buttons, text labels. I just ran Java Monkey to test the Bridge and it appears to have successfully loaded the tree of the application.

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure the JAWS demo license limits you to 40 minutes and only works with browsers. So you can't test any applications.

I am trying to find confirmation, but am sadly unable to find any information on their website.